# Evaluate an instantiation in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, extjs4

I want to evaluate a string in javascript. The string that I want to be evaluated is an instantiation of a class:

```
var frm = eval("new MyDesktop.Modules." 
    + record.data.js 
    + ".Client." 
    +  record.data.js + "();")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information?

Comment: Is it not working? I would think it would in its current form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but you don't need to do that.

```
var js = record.get('js');
var frm = Ext.create('MyDesktop.Modules.' + js + '.Client.' +  js');
```

Comment: Anything that avoids an `eval` gets my +1 :P